# Testing with Ant - Cannot test files in subdirectories

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, ant

I have an android application in java. I want to test it using a xml script with ant. Now we have several packages and a standard directory structure for our source and test files.
There is a "tests" folder (root of all test code) which has 1 file say A.java and some sub-folders which again in-turn contain some test files or sub-sub-folders. Only file A.java gets tested and rest others are not tested. If i change the directory path in xml script from "tests" to say "tests/ui" then test files in folder "ui" are not able to test and i get some error - Class Not Found Error when i check out the files in "test-result" folder where i store the output of the test.

I have included the parent directory of compiled codes and required external jars in path with id = "test.classpath".  I think i should every file of type .class rather then path to parent folder.

The code is :

```
<target name="test-run" description="Run Test">
     <delete dir = "test_result" />
     <mkdir dir = "test_result" />
     <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" showoutput="yes" >
        <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
        <batchtest fork="yes" todir="test_result">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <fileset dir="tests" includes="**/*" />
        </batchtest>
     </junit>
 </target>
```

Can you please explain me how to achieve my motive assuming a generic file structure.

EDIT :

Following is the path used in above xml where folder out contains .class files of source and test files generated by idea ide :

```
  <path id="test.classpath">
    <pathelement path="testlibs/jmockit.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="testlibs/jmockit-coverage.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="testlibs/jmockit-coverage-htmlfull.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="/opt/idea-IU-117.418/lib/junit-4.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement path="out"/>
  </path>
```

Comment: Can you post the test.classpath as well?

Comment: i have edited the questn to include it.

Comment: ok, my first test was getting failed and i had haltonfailure="yes".. my bad.. thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `fileset`element to this:

```
<fileset dir="tests" includes="**/*.java" />
```

Comment: thanks, but that was the first thing i tried.. then since all files in tests folder are .java, i removed it.

Comment: also, there is a second part to my question that talks about class not found problem.. any ideas on that?

Comment: Did you mean to have ${test.classpath}?

Comment: no.. i have not defined it as property.. it is simply a variable name.. used from sources from where i read about testing with ant..